# windows phone 7 bing map

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am showing bing map on RoadMode in my wp7 application. But I want to use bing map that **showing cafes or similar places** in my wp7 application. What is the mode of that bing map?and how can I take that place location information?

Comment: YOU have to know what cafes or similar places you wish to display, and their coordinates. Then you can just draw them on the map using a MapPin layer.

Comment: You misunderstood me, I will explain more clearly. I am working on meeting application. 
User will choose any meeting point on the map, that point can be any where. 
Then that meeting point(cafe or somewhere else) will be sent to the other user as a meeting request.

Comment: with no POI's? you're either describing multiple questions which you didn't do due-diligence on, or you're looking for a complex architectural design for a POI / meeting request sharing app / webservice.

Comment: I am new to issue, I don't know that technology very well. I am only curious about can I do that with today technology 
if the answer is yes what tools should I use? For example,
on the google earth we can see cafes, otels and similar places.
Is it not possible showing a map like that on windows phone 7 application.
I am able to show only streets in my phone application

Answer (score -1):

You need to use different API of BING Maps to get data. Like Point of Interests or Spatial Data services of bing maps below is the link which will help you getting data from Bing Maps using Spatial Data Services

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh757509.aspx